# Devexpress spin - culture info

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, culture

Estou usando o spinedit da devexpress, com MVC, é um campo decimal, mas eu preciso que a pontuação do número seja um ponto e não uma vírgula, preciso colocar a cultura dele como "en-US", como fazer?

Comment: Você já tentou mudar o "culture" no web.config?

Answer (score 2):

Se os componentes da spinedit estiverem usando o padrão do .Net, é só alterar, preferencialmente para a execução inteira do site, no global.asax:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Comment: E eu votando em tudo do cara só porque foi no MVP CC :D

Answer (score 0):

Depende do Tipo de Aplicação.
Se for WindowForms basta o seguinte :

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR")
```

Se for WPF acrescente:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
  GetType(FrameworkElement), 
  New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)))
```

Nao esqueca dos Imports

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Markup
```